# Transform string with selected case capitalization

Tags: javascript

Looking for a function that takes a string and position(s) of a character(s) and makes the whole thing lower case but then upper cases the position(s) passed. Not sure what the best way to achieve this is, especially with the possibility of transforming more than one character? Any thoughts?

Comment: What have you got so far? Posting your current work will help you get more answers.

Comment: This sounds like one of those "I'm trying to solve problem A by doing B so how do I do B?" -- maybe there's a better way of solving problem A though.  What's your original use case?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/xcBrz/1/

Comment: @andi - this is the use case. I have a bunch of "special condition" variable names that I have to account for and transform to the proper case which can be passed in any format (case wise).

Comment: @y0ruba - sorry I wasn't clear enough, i'm looking for a way to transform different characters in the same string. Example: puRchASEID --> purchaseID or scadd --> scAdd or SCCHECKOUT --> scCheckout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so based on what you said your real use case was: 
"I have a bunch of "special condition" variable names that I have to account for and transform to the proper case which can be passed in any format (case wise)."

In that case, I would make an array of those variable names:

```
var names = ["purchaseID", "scAdd", "scCheckout"];
```

then compare a lowercase version of each with a lowercase version of the passed in parameter, and if they are equal, set the passed in parameter equal to the value stored in your array:

```
var transformString = function(str) {
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        if (str.toLowerCase() === names[i].toLowerCase()){
            return names[i];
        }
    }
};
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Acb4/

Answer (score 1):

Im not gonna give you the code to fix this, but I can give you a push:

- take the string and lowercase it
- take that string and `.split()` it (use it like that, no value in split)

Now you have each character in an array, and you can access every Nth character via `characterArray[N-1]` where N stands for the position:

```
characterArray[N-1] = characterArray[N-1].toUpperCase();
```

In the end, use `.join()` to string it again. The -1 is to correct to zero-indexed, the arrays first key is `0`, not `1`